# Decode special characters before PDO insert?

Tags: php, pdo, decode, htmlspecialchars

If I am using `htmlspecialchars` in order to output what the user may have already entered in a form, does it make sense for me to `htmlspecialchars_decode` those values before they are binded in a PDO statement?

For example, let's say I have a form element like this:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo trim(htmlspecialchars('first_name', ENT_QUOTES)); ?>">
```

Should I then use the following code before binding the values in the PDO query:

```
$first_name = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['first_name']));
$stm->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
```

Or is this overkill?

Answer (score 0):

You can first replace the text entered in the textbox with some values like
str_replace('@','-',$str) and so on.